# tag:citations and tag:case-citations

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I notice that there is overlap between the tags [citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) and [case-citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/case-citations).

[citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations):

- 15 questions, 11 of which are about citation practice (i.e. referencing or giving attribution for) materials, some of which are cases, but others are legislative material
- 4 of the questions are about *receiving* a citation (i.e. something like a ticket or fine for commiting an infraction)

[case-citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/case-citations):

- 35 questions, all of which are about citation styles (with the exception of one, which is asking *for* a particular case as an answer)

How should we deal with these?

Answer (score 3):

I propose we create a new tag, [legal-citation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-citation), which would handle all questions about the style and practice of legal citations, whether it be to cases, legislative material, or any other source in the context of legal writing.

[case-citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/case-citations) and [citation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation) (and maybe [legal-citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-citations)) would become tag synonyms for [legal-citation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-citation).

I propose that there is no need to use any particular tag for questions about *receiving* a citation (i.e. something like a ticket or fine for commiting an infraction). Rather, those questions need only be tagged according to the substantive area of law under which the infraction arises (e.g. [traffic](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic)). The four questions currently tagged [citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) with that meaning would be untagged.

---

Progress:

- tag [legal-citation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-citation) applied to three recent questions
- [synonyms proposed](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/legal-citation/synonyms) and have been approved
- tag [citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) have all manually been retagged to [legal-citation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-citation) with the exception of the few that were about tickets/fines
- [case-citations](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/case-citations) has been [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet/119377#119377) into [legal-citation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-citation)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Jen](https://forum.bnfworld.com/topic/6958-cheets-aspiring-adventurer/), I propose:

### Retag some to [tickets](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tickets)

The 4 cases of receiving a citation might better be retagged as [ticket](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ticket) or something similar